# Correlation and Linear Regression

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients

1) I would like to know if the value Pearson Correlation r obtained in running a Correlation between two dependent variables will be the r that is obtained in a regression correlation (the square root of R-square).

2) Is it statistically correct to say that "a regression analysis was conducted to examine the Pearson Correlation r between the independent var X and a dependent var Y"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1: Yes, for a simple linear regression $R^2 = \hat{\rho}_{x,y}^2$.

Point 2: This is a clunky sentence, though technically correct. I would say something like:

> The Pearson correlation between $x$ and $y$ was 0.58.

Comment: I see, so we can use regression analysis to find out Pearson Moment Correlation r